# Error while trying to load module environment in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a makefile and I'm trying to load some modules before running the target. Here is the makefile:

```
CC=g++        
all:
        . /usr/share/Modules/init/bash
        module load gcc/4.8.1
        module load opencv
        module load python/2.7.5
        $(CC) -std=gnu++11 -lstdc++ -fPIC -shared -o .......
clean:
        rm ../../lib/linux/extract_features.so
```

But when I run `make` command, it gives me this error:

```
/usr/share/Modules/init/bash_completion: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/share/Modules/init/bash_completion: line 14: ` comm -23  <(_module_avail|sort)  <(tr : '\n' <<<${LOADEDMODULES}|sort)'
/usr/share/Modules/init/bash_completion: line 14: warning: syntax errors in . or eval will cause future versions of the shell to abort as Posix requires
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

If I just run `. /usr/share/Modules/init/bash` in the terminal, it does not give me any error.

How can I load modules in a makefile?Any suggestion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default shell for running make recipes is `/bin/sh` not `/bin/bash`. You can override that by assigning to the [`SHELL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell) variable. (Note the addition of `.SHELLFLAGS` in make 4.0.)

Additionally, each line of a recipe is run in its own shell session so a line like `module load opencv` will load that module in a shell session that then *immediately* exits so the next line `module load python/2.7.5` will not have it loaded.

You need to either write all the commands on a single line or tell make that they are one continued line by using `\` at the end of each line (and making sure to have the right `;`/`&`/etc. terminators between the lines for the shell (as make will run it as one single line when it runs it).

```
CC=g++
SHELL:=/bin/bash

all:
        . /usr/share/Modules/init/bash; \
        module load gcc/4.8.1; \
        module load opencv; \
        module load python/2.7.5; \
        $(CC) -std=gnu++11 -lstdc++ -fPIC -shared -o .......

clean:
        rm ../../lib/linux/extract_features.so
```